# Default Keyboard appears in iPhone instead of my custom keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, custom-controls

I am making a custom keyboard in my app for iPhone. But when I tap on the UITextField the default keyboard also appears. Where as I want only my keyboard to pop-up on the screen. How do I stop default keyboard from appearing on the screen?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following line of code

```
your_TextField.inputView = your_CustomKeyboard;
```

I am not confirm that it will work for your custom Keyboard i tried this to use a datepicker as inputview and it did worked so it may help you

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question. Since I am new here i cudnt post an answer b4 8 hrs after my own question post. And yes Tejeshwar Gill, Thanks for the response and my solution matches your approach. Thanks again.

I used the NSNotificationCenter to notify me when the keyboard appears. I had used this method to resize my tableview when the keyboard appears, but that was quite some time before. So it didnt click me instantly then.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(hideKeyboard:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

Comment: so in your hideKeyboard method, what did you do?  Could you show the code please?

Answer (score -1):

You need to hide the default keyboard inorder to show your custom keyboard. So use this:-

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];` and in the method `keyboardDidHide:` , add `[keyboard resignFirstResponder]`.